# Foreach error if only single record exists in the import csv - Laravel blade

Tags: php, laravel, foreach

I have an import feature where users can import records from a .csv file. It works fine if the user is importing a file with multiple records but if one tries to import a .csv that has only one record it throws an error, "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" and spits out this reference code for the error.

```
<?php $__currentLoopData = $line; $__env->addLoop($__currentLoopData); foreach($__currentLoopData as $field): $__env->incrementLoopIndices(); $loop = $__env->getLastLoop(); ?>
```

As stated this error only occurs when there is a single record in the import .csv, if one were to add additional records to the .csv the import feature the process works fine.

Here is the blade's foreach code, what's going on?

```
<table class="table">
 @if (isset($headers))
     <tr>
       @foreach ($headers as $field)
           <th>{{ $field }}</th>
       @endforeach
      </tr>
 @endif
 @if($lines)
     @foreach ($lines as $line)
      <tr>
       @foreach ($line as $field)
           <td>{{ $field }}</td>
       @endforeach
      </tr>
     @endforeach
 @endif
     <tr>
         @foreach ($headers as $key => $header)
           <td>
              <select name="fields[{{ $key }}]">
                 <option value=''>Please select</option>
                     @foreach ($fillables as $k => $fillable)
                        <option value="{{ $fillable }}"
                            @if (strtolower($header) === strtolower($fillable)) selected @endif>{{ $fillable  }}</option>
                     @endforeach
              </select>
           </td>
      @endforeach
    </tr>
  </table>
```

Here is the controller

```
public function parse(Request $request)
    {
        $file = $request->file('csv_file');
        $request->validate([
            'csv_file' => 'mimes:csv,txt',
        ]);

        $path = $file->path();
        $hasHeader = $request->input('header', false) ? true : false;

        $reader = new SpreadsheetReader($path);
        $headers = $reader->current();
        $lines = [];
        $lines[] = $reader->next();
        $lines[] = $reader->next();

        $filename = Str::random(10).'.csv';
        $file->storeAs('csv_import', $filename);

        $modelName = $request->input('model', false);
        $fullModelName = 'App\\'.$modelName;

        $model = new $fullModelName();
        $fillables = $model->getFillable();

        $church_id = $request->input('church_id');
        $interest_tags = $request->input('interest_tags');

        if ($modelName == 'Interest') {
            $custom_fields = CustomField::where('created_by_team_id', $church_id)->pluck('name')->toArray();
            if (! empty($custom_fields)) {
                $fillables = array_merge($fillables, $custom_fields);
            }
        }

        $is_adding_new_religious_background = $request->input('is_adding_new_religious_background', false) ? true : false;

        $redirect = url()->previous();

        return view(
            'csvImport.parse_import',
            compact('headers', 'filename', 'fillables', 'church_id', 'interest_tags', 'hasHeader', 'modelName', 'lines', 'redirect', 'is_adding_new_religious_background')
        );
```

How does one modify this so that it functions for both single record and multi-record imports?

Comment: As a possible solution try to typecast to array right in place a variable used in foreach. Smth like: `foreach((array)$lines as ...`

Comment: seems to me like `$line` is non-iterable.. try `@dd($line)` and make sure it's not null and is an array?

Comment: well make the code in the two cases, check if it is an array, if so do a foreach, else print just the line

Comment: Why you used `$lines[] = $reader->next();` twice?

Comment: @Daniel Well that is a bloody good question. I didn't notice that. I went back through my commits to see if I did that as an edit for any particular reason but it does not look like it. It looks like I just inadvertently duplicated it twice and failed to notice the redundancy. You found the issue, I removed it and it seems like it fixed the issues with the single record import while thankfully it does not seem to have any negative effect on anything else. Thanks for your eagle eye I appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check the second @foreach in your blade template. You need to check if if $line is empty before loop.